# CSS Grid: how to create a "half height" row

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

I've been trying to create a specific layout, but I'm pretty new to css grid, and I'm at a loss as to why the following codepen doesn't work, can anyone help?

As far as I can tell this should create a 3x3 grid with a = 2x1 b = 1x2 c = 1x2 d = 1x2 e = 1x1, but e didn't seem to fall into line.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
    grid-auto-rows: 100px;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #444;
    }

    .box {
        background-color: #444;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 150%;

    }

    .a {
        grid-column: 1 / 3;
        grid-row: 1;
    }
    .b {
        grid-column: 3;
        grid-row: 1 / 3;
    }
    .c {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 2 / 4;
    }
    .d {
        grid-column: 2;
        grid-row: 2 / 4;
    }
   .e {
        grid-column: 3;
        grid-row: 3;
    }
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LeJNxG

Comment: The code in your question is fine. The code in your pen has hidden characters that are messing things up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I replicated the code and in my case E cell is in-line.
Have a look https://codepen.io/navdeepsingh/pen/LeJWOv

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
    grid-auto-rows: 100px;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #444;
    }

    .box {
        background-color: #444;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 150%;

    }

    .a {
        grid-column: 1 / 3;
        grid-row: 1;
    }
    .b {
        grid-column: 3;
        grid-row: 1 / 3;
    }
    .c {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 2 / 4;
    }
    .d {
        grid-column: 2;
        grid-row: 2 / 4;
    }
   .e {
        grid-column: 3;
        grid-row: 3;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Correct. In the Codepen of the OP there is a nbsp before element E